# Find and replace inside a string variable using sed command - shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

lets say I have a string variable variable

```
var="This line is with OldText"
```

I want to find and replace the text inside this variable
The method that I tried is,

```
echo $var | sed -i "s/OldText/NewText/g"  >> result.log
```

in this case this gives an error saying "no input files".
The expected output is ,

```
"This line is with NewText"
```

what is the correct method to do this using sed, awk or any other method.

Comment: Remove `-i` option from it, its for inplace editing and you are Good to go, cheers.

Comment: Optionally you could: `echo $var >> result.log && sed -i "s/OldText/NewText/g" result.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `-i`, as that's for changing a file in place. If you want to replace the value in the variable, you need to reassign to it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ var=$(sed "s/OldText/NewText/" <<< $var)
$ echo $var
This line is with NewText
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bash shell, you could:

```
$ echo ${var/OldText/NewText}
This line is with NewText
```

so

```
$ var=${var/OldText/NewText}
```

See [this](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for more.